# React Navigation V5 neasting navigators has problem

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

**i have problem with navigation.goBack()**

hi, i have an app in which i am using drawer and stack navigator,,, my navigation structure is as follows

```
Stack:
  - Drawer :
      - Main
      - List
      - rest Screens
  - Details
  - rest screens
```

List page will have initial parameters, in List page i am navigating to Details page... on navigating back using navigation.goBack()it will go to Main page not to ListPage... i want to go to ListPage

i am using react-navigation v5